# How do I handle this exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF Toolkit DataGrid with the `ItemsSource` property bound to a `DataTable`. The DataTable has a unique constraint on one of the columns. If I try to enter non-unique data into the column an exception is thrown (which is good) from an area of code I can't get to and then the application crashes (which is bad).

How do I catch or otherwise cause this exception to be handled so that the application doesn't crash?

Comment: Could you show some code please? Also do you catch the exception and what do you do in the catch statement

Comment: @Hasanain, what code do you want to see? No I don't catch the exception but I want to - hence the question.

Comment: Am assuming you have a library/dll that you don't have the source to, the exception bubbles up to your code... so could you show code, as to where/how you use the dataTable...

Comment: The binding is declared in XAML so I don't have access to any code to wrap in a try catch. I'm assuming there is another way to handle this kind of binding exception.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `IDataErrorInfo` in your `ViewModel` and check on the data entered? If data isn't unique, define an error, an `Exception` won't be thrown, your `TextBox` will just be colored in red showing you that an error happened (more info here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked around this problem by adding a kind of validation to the `CellEditEnding` event on the `DataGrid`. I set `e.Cancel` to `true` if validation fails.

It's probably not the right way to go about fixing this problem but it has the desired end result.

Comment: That is a viable workaround.  If you ever move away from DataTable and into object data, you can set your data classes to implement IDataErrorInfo and use that to perform validation.  WPF uses this very well and on error, you can display a ValidationErrorTemplate item that modifies the control(s) to give the user information on how properly to edit the field/property.  Check out